# Adding a section for Nintex related issues on the left side would be useful?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Checking how many questions are here in **SharePoint** I realized there aren't so many for **Nintex** products. As you may know, **Nintex** has some products largely used in SharePoint On-Prem and Online environments. I'm also a user in Nintex community to ask for advice and for solving issues so I know how useful is and how many articles and solutions are there.

I was wondering if it would be useful to add a new box on the right side of this **SharePoint** channel when asking or answering a **Nintex** question with those related questions got from **Nintex Community**.

Do you think that kind of components joins the Stackoverflow flavor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All paid-for third party products related to SharePoint have their own support channels, and sometimes even their own forum. As in the case with Nintex, where I also have an account and have asked questions. By that it's not really suited for this site where we work with SharePoint and open-source free products and add-ons.

Please use the [Nintex community](https://community.nintex.com/) for Nitex specific questions.

EDIT

That's why we can close questions, regarding 3rd party software:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about your last point. I mean, there is a "nintex" tag we can use for asking about their products. I know you meant to use the specific products forums for finding specific help but we are able to ask for those questions here as well.

Comment: @jaloplo See edited answer

Comment: thanks for the answer. totally understood.